# FullCalendar End Dates Past Midnight on ListView

Tags: fullcalendar

In ListWeek View, it seems all end times render as midnight even if the event extends beyond midnight. I have provided an accurate "end" value in the events json.

I totally see the value in this, but is there an override to list the actual end time of say 2am here.

I have nextDayThreshold set into the next morning which does a good job of keeping the event as showing as two separate events in list view, but it still renders the end time as midnight which is misleading.

Comment: Well, each day is independent in that view, so I don't think there's really anything you can do about it. The timeline view can run the days together so that the event would overlap midnight in a single display